# using Golang context.WithValue in testing for http request

Tags: unit-testing, go, graphql, go-echo, go-testing

I am trying to do unit testing, I am using GraphQL `gqlgen` for this case with Echo, I have been struggle to do test with my context, I can't add **header** in my testing due the GraphQL not using the server endpoint
here is my code to set the context value

```
var ctx *http.Request
var echo echo.Context

h := context.WithValue(ctx.Context(), "Token", token)
tk := ctx.WithContext(h)
echo.SetRequest(tk)
```

I do this on middleware function when I run my server, nothing issue,
here is how I call that in my resolver

```
// c is context.Context
tokenHeader = c.Value("Token")
```

but in testing I create that codes
always got:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1703953]

goroutine 30 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.1(0x17b3000, 0x1f47810)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:940 +0x2f5
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc000378900)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:943 +0x3f9
panic(0x17b3000, 0x1f47810)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
spur/test.TestCredential.func3(0xc000378900)
        /Users/me/Documents/project/test/main_test.go:144 +0x193
testing.tRunner(0xc000378900, 0xc00034fdf0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:991 +0xdc
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1042 +0x357
```

is it possible to set the context value during in test?

here is may full testing code:

```
func TestCredential(t *testing.T)  {
    config := resolver.Config{
        Resolvers: resolver.New(),
    }

    clientTest := testClient.New(handler.NewDefaultServer(resolver.NewExecutableSchema(config)))

    t.Run("Should Success Change Password", func(t *testing.T) {
        var ctx *http.Request
        var echo echo.Context

        h := context.WithValue(ctx.Context(), "Token", token)
        tk := ctx.WithContext(h)
        echo.SetRequest(tk)


        var respond map[string]interface{}
        mutation := `mutation {
                      changeCredentialConfirmation(
                        currentPassword: ""
                        newChange: "newPassword"
                        isForgotPassword: true
                        isChangePassword: false
                      )
                    }`
        clientTest.MustPost(
            mutation,
            &respond,
        )
        require.True(t, respond["changeCredentialConfirmation"].(bool), "Check your email")
    })
}
```

Comment: You need add *header* or *context.Value*? they are different things btw.

Comment: Where are you initializing ctx? That is probably why you are getting nil pointer error.

Comment: I use `ctx` inside func `TestMyMiddleWare(t *testing.T) { // code here }` @AshwinShirva

Comment: @Зелёный contex.Value what I need I think, any idea?

Comment: because in my resolver I call ` c.Value("Token")` so I think I need to add context.Value in my unit testing function @Зелёный

Comment: What point in code is the nil pointer error thrown? Can you post the full error stack please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add your project structure as well as the full error stack.

Comment: I just updated my question, look new update :) @AshwinShirva

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215944/discussion-between-ashwin-shirva-and-weq-iou).

Comment: I am on the root chat @AshwinShirva